# How do i make this pattern from user input using a for loop (i want my code to be able to produce the output on the bottom)

Tags: python

```
Size = int(input("what is the size of the box "))

def Stars(Size):
  for x in range(0, Size):
    for y in range(0, Size):
      print("*",end="")
Stars()
```

```
OUTPUT (if the size of the box was 4)
        ****
        *==*
        *==*
        ****
```

Comment: you want to print `=`  for middle ones?

Comment: yeah thats what i wanted to do, also i wanted it so if you type a number 1 higher it adds another symbol like ***==***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first and last line, they should be outside the loop. Then you can create the loop normally,

```
def stars(x):
    print('*'*x)
    for i in range(1,x-1):
        print('*'+'='*(x-2)+'*')
    print('*'*x)

stars(4)
```

Comment: ok thank you very much but im new to python so what is the 4th line doing?

Comment: you want 1 star, followed by (x-2; here: 4-2=2) `=` signs then another star. @pythonnub

Comment: ok also would this work if i put another size such as 5 or would i have to change the code. like size = 5 so it prints same thing but extra symbol in each one

Comment: @python yes exactly, try to play around with the code and see how it works. You can try to comment out certain lines to see what changes or modify the numbers and check their effect.

Comment: is the for loop doing the rows of the stars or the column? edit(ok i will play with the code and see if it works)

Answer (score 0):

Try this lambda function

```
box = lambda columns: [print(('*'*columns if c==0 or c==columns-1 else '*'+'='*(columns-2)+'*')) for c in range(columns)]
```

Comment: thank you, this works too

Comment: hello since Mohammad did not answer can you please explain what the for loop in his code does?

Comment: @pythonnub for sure. Let’s say you want a 5x5 box. First, it will print a row of 5 stars. Then, he prints 3 rows. The first character is ‘\*’, and then he prints 5-2 ‘=‘, or 3 ‘=‘. Then he prints another ‘\*’. It loops 3 times because he did ```for i in range(1, 5-1)```. Since range is exclusive, this just means it gives 1 the first time, then 2 the second, then 3 the third. The last thing is it just repeats the first line. The difference between my code and his, besides the fact that mine is 1 line, is it can also give box length 1, whereas his prints out two columns of 1 star.

Comment: thank you i understand so much better now

Answer (score 0):

```py
def Stars(x = int(input("Enter size of box"))):  
   print("*" * x)  
   for i in range(1, x - 1):  
     print("*"+"="*(x - 2)+ "*")  
   print("*"* x)   
Stars()
```